# Matching two images using VideoGrabber with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

I' trying to match one image from `VideoGrabber` and another image that is on disk.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html).

The problem is that it uses the function `imread`, which takes a string (path of the file), incompatible with `VideGrabber` type.

How can I convert a `VideoGrabber` from openframeworks data type to opencv mat type?

Comment: As it stands the question is very unclear. Where does VideoGrabber object come from? what does it mean to convert VideoGrabber object to string or to image? Are you saying that image, VideoGrabber object and string are similar data types and you can just cast them from one type to another?

Comment: I do not see how that is ambiguous if I have the tag openframeworks. This is a question about the tool openframeworks. VideoGrabber is an object capturing a sequence of images from the camera. http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoGrabber.html

Comment: your question is very vague and doesn't make much sense. Why should I guess stuff from your poorly written question? If you want to convert an image from openframeworks data type to opencv mat type just say so. Again I'm just guessing, I'm not a mind reader and still have no clue what you trying to achieve. You can edit your own question to make it more clear. otherwise you not going to get much help here.

Comment: Yes, it is fair. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
ofVideoGrabber vidGrabber;
...
cv::Mat frame(vidGrabber.getHeight(), vidGrabber.getWidth(), CV_8UC3, vidGrabber.getPixels());
```

I am not sure what format uses to pack pixels, OpenCV uses BGR interleaved channels, you may have to swap pixels around.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems to be a specific question about openframworks. You can use the wonderful addon [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) fro Kyle, it is specifically for an alternative use of opencv library inside openframeworks.

in ofxCv you can find methods such as `toCv` for converting openframeworks types to opencv, and `toOf`, for the inverse process. Have a look, it is well documented, with a lot of examples, and well designed.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what difficulty you have with string versus `array char[]`.  Array of chars can be converted to string like this:

```
char myarray[ ] = "my_file_name";
string str(myarray);
```

Comment: According to the link http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html the string is the file name, then the VideoGrabber would have to constantly save an image to disk, which does not seem to be very efficient.

Comment: what is VideoGrabber object, where does it come from?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: I do not see how that is ambiguous if I have the tag openframeworks. This is a question about the tool openframeworks. VideoGrabber is an object capturing a sequence of images from the camera. http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoGrabber.html